# adding row to a p:datatable with requestScope managed bean where i have a form validation

Tags: forms, jsf-2, primefaces

I've read the [using-databatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) for BalusC and i tried the sample to add a row using request scope but i found a problem is that when i add the

```
<h:inputHidden binding="#{myBean.dataItemId}" />
```

all buttons of my page will not work. at first i thought the problem is from the converter

```
<h:inputHidden binding="#{myBean.dataItemId}" converter="javax.faces.Integer"/>
```

but also without the converter the same problem i have

second the more interesting is that i didn't understand from the sample code how when adding a new row to the datatable the table gets my added rows before

example if i add the first row and put data the second row while adding i realized that the add function creates a new `ArrayList` where i think it will deletes the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the top "Notice" block of that article, it is targeted on JSF 1.2. Adding a row can much easier be achieved using the JSF 2.0 view scope.

Based on the example given in the JSF 1.2 article, you just need to make 2 changes:

1. Put the bean in the view scope.
2. Remove the whole `<h:inputHidden>` and the `addCount` property and any references on it.

Here's a kickoff example in JSF 2.0 flavor:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Item> items;

    @EJB
    private ItemService service; // Or just DAO. Whatever you want.

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = service.list();
    }

    public void add() {
        items.add(new Item());
    }

    public void save() {
        service.save(items);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() { 
        return items;
    }

}
```

And the view:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" rendered="#{item.id != null}" />
        <h:outputText value="new" rendered="#{item.id == null}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" rendered="#{item.id != null}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{item.name}" rendered="#{item.id == null}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" rendered="#{item.id != null}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" rendered="#{item.id == null}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.add}" />
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" />
```